# 12V DC to 5V DC with an output current of 2A

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

I'm trying to convert 12V to 5V using cheap parts; zener and transistor.

[image: schematic]

Now I want to gain the output current to 1A or 2A, I want to use this circuit to make mobile charger

Any ideas and if there any improvement to this circuit?

Answer (score 4):

2 amps thru 22 ohms produces a volt drop of 44 volts so it won't work.

The output voltage will be about 4 volts under load ignoring the 22 ohm problem.

Ignoring the above, the power dissipation in the transistor will be about 15 watts at full load.

I'd use a buck converter because if you are looking for low cost then you need to take into account cost of ownership i.e. all those watts thrown away in heat won't be charged for by your electricity supply company with a buck converter. It may be pennies a day but it soon mounts up.

Comment: Even if the electricity is free, a buck converter will be cheaper than the infrastructure to deal with the heat.

Comment: That is exactly the point I wanted to make in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

On the back of an enveloppe:
12 V in - 5 V out = 7 V drop at 2 A = 7 x 2 = 14 W
You will need to dissipate 14 Watts ! For that you will need a decent size heatsink.

Also, you want this to be cheap, the cheapest solution I know is a buck converter.
They are less than $ 1.30 on ebay: http://www.ebay.nl/itm/Hot-DC-DC-Buck-GS-Converter-Step-Down-Module-LM2596-Power-OU-Output-1-23V-30V-/371399927333?hash=item5679292625

You will be unable to beat that $ 1.30 by using a linear (non switching) solution as
proposed in your schematic.

So indeed: get a buck converter module to do this.

Sidenote: A switching converter is also much more efficient, in this case a linear regulator converts more than half the energy into heat which is a waste. A switching converter only loses about 10 % of the power.

Comment: could you give me the buck converter circuit????

Comment: The converter I suggested is based on an LM2596. The schematic is in the datasheet of the LM2596. But note that it will cost much more to source all the components separately and build a working converter and note that it won't work if you don't make a proper layout and use the correct type of inductor like mentioned in the datasheet than the module I suggested costs.